# Worksheet.Protect doesn't apply a password

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I have a workbook which has a macro that copies some data into a second file then tries to protect the resulting worksheet (and workbook) with code along these lines:

```
OutputWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=pw, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
OutputWb.Protect Password:=pw, Structure:=True, Windows:=False
```

The issue is, when I then open up the `OutputWb` file, I can unprotect both sheet and workbook without it ever asking me for the password.

What am I doing wrong, here?  Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, of course.

`pw` should actually be `"pw"`.  It was looking for a variable instead of the string...

Because I hadn't set `Option Explicit`, it wasn't worrying about the fact that the variable has never been declared or anything like that.  :/